# Null Pointer Exception error, even when trying to catch null

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, integer, break

I'm using Bukkit's API, but I'll snip out some code from it, as it's not the API (because it's not introduced in what i am doing). So, I keep receiving a 'Null Pointer Exception', and after searching Google I couldn't seem to relate any fixes to my code. So here's my code:

```
Integer tier = null;
    for(Integer i = 1; i <= 5;) 
    {
        if (p.hasPermission("flyp.fly." + i.toString())){
            tier = i - 1;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

if(tier == null) 
    {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You lack the permission to do this!");
            return true;
    }
```

When this code is used, (when I use '/fly on', the event) I get a 'Null Pointer Exception', and it's pointed to the line 'if(tier == null)'. Lastly, I was cleaning up "old" code, and this section was written by my friend that I can't seem to contact -_-.

Thanks for the help,
AhellHound

Comment: Make sure the executing code (that's throwing the exception) is the same as the code you're looking at. It could be the line number reported with the error is a different line if the source has changed since the executing code was compiled.

Comment: Ya I checked a few times, and I did tests by omitting some lines, and they all pointed to that line.

Comment: Can you turn this into a complete compilable example? It looks like you've omitted some stuff here, which may actually turn out to be the crux of the matter.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: if (tier == null) will for sure not throw a NullPointerEception, so the code you are looking now is another one that throwed the Exception. In this code only when p is null an Nullpointer Exception can happen.